# Rails - Include different assets for mobile and desktop for an AngularJS app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

How can I include a different set of assets (CSS and JavaScript) for AngularJS views designed for phones and AngularJS views designed for desktop from a Rails API?  The default template (application.html.erb or index.html) would typically only be loaded once, with the initial request, because it's an AngularJS application, so I do not think the usual desktop vs. mobile solutions for Rails apps will work.

Specifically, I am trying to combine a desktop app that uses AngularJS, Bootstrap, and jQuery with a mobile app that uses AngularJS and Ionic.  The two apps will mostly have shared code, except for the views.  The views will be very different, so a responsive approach will not be enough.  I have not been able to find much guidance on this at all.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 4.1 offers [variants](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants) so that you can have different view templates depending on the display type. Here's a more thorough [example](http://bobonrails.com/post/72213272339/more-responsive-layouts). It's really recent so there's not a lot out there about them yet.

If you're not on 4.1, you can look at using the [Mobylette](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette) gem to achieve the [same thing](https://dev.tscolari.me/2011/09/15/how-to-build-a-mobile-rails-3-dot-1-app/). You can then also have a completely different `application.mobile.erb` that includes different assets.

For flipping between which assets you're including, you can also take a look at this (the helper method part), but this won't address the issue with different sets of views across the board:

[Mobile style switching in Rails 3, helper method vs media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783084/mobile-style-switching-in-rails-3-helper-method-vs-media-queries)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write up of the various options.  I think that I'll go with the helper method of mobile style switching.